# Irreducible factors of number in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I have to give a irreducible factor decomposition of $11$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3]$. I know that I have to use factors of the form $(a+b\sqrt{3})$ but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: As this seems like a homework assignment; are there any theorems or examples about such a ring in your literature so far?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You are looking for two factors of the form $a+b\sqrt{3}$ and $c+d\sqrt{3}$ such that

$$(a+b\sqrt{3})(c+d\sqrt{3})=11.$$

Note that $11=11+0\sqrt{3}$, thus you have to solve a system like this:

\begin{cases}
ac+3bd=11\\
ad+cb=0
\end{cases}

Comment: If the system haven't solution means that $11$ is irreducible. I am sure that it isn't a square.

Comment: This is what I needed! I didn't have any examples. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so this system does not have a solution where a,b,c,d are integers. It means 11 is irreducible in $Z[\sqrt{3}]$, right?

Comment: In this case there is a solution of the system